# Substrate for exterior paver blocks to achieve grading

Tags: drainage, exterior, underlayment, pavers

I am putting some paver blocks around my shed, which is small enough not to have gutters so I would like the immediate surrounding, most of which will be covered by these blocks, to be graded away from the foundation. What should I put below the soil and the pavers in order to achieve mild gradation of about 5-10 degrees? Sand or gravel or something third? The area is already excavated so there isn't enough native dirt.

Comment: using a porous matrix aggregate like sand or gravel will allow the water to sink right where it lands instead of running away. you want something more like clay or solid concrete. You might be able to treat the existing fill with lime to reduce it's absorption, but if the ground is clear, i would put something waterproof, like a roof membrane, under the other aggregate.

Comment: Are these pavers simply gonna be placed on the ground?  Anything wrong with putting down some rubber sheet, like a shower pan liner, then putting your pavers on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost any inorganic material of medium to small granule size will do. Use what's on hand and inexpensive.

- sand
- gravel
- crushed (recycled) concrete
- crushed rock

I'd avoid "river rock" and similar as it's slippery, so it tends to shift under loads. Organic soils tend to get mushy when saturated, and they may decay further and settle more.

I'd also overlay landscape fabric before you set your pavers to help prevent weeds. If you want maximum drainage and don't care about mold underneath, heavy poly sheeting also works.